# Format date columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| date_1 | date_2 | date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0020-01-31 | 0020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 |
| 0021-01-01 | 0021-12-31 | 2021-02-28 |
| 0021-01-01 | 0021-12-31 | 2021-02-28 |

AS the date_1 is string, so I have to replace 0020 to 2020 first as it is year
but I am getting no change in the dataframe

```
my_df = my_df.replace(regex=['0020'], value='2020')
my_df.head()
```

Thanks for Help in advance!

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: NB
You could also just replace `00` for `20` if you don't have anything before 2000.
`replace(regex=['^00'], value='20')`

Answer (score 1):

Well in theory you'd like to correct **all** the bad dates in every column, not just `2020`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date_1":["0020-01-01", "0021-01-02", "0000-01-03"], "date_2":["0020-01-01", "0021-01-02", "0000-01-03"], "date_3":["2020-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2000-01-03"]}) 

df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace("^00", "20", regex=True))
```

**FOLLOW UP**

If some of columns are made of `Timestamp` and not `str`, the method above will fail. The following will avoid that problem but it needs the help of library `re` (as far as I know, you cannot use regex with normal str `replace`):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df["date_3"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_3"])

def swap(x): return re.sub("^00", "20", x) if type(x) is str else x

df.applymap(swap)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        date1       date2       date3
0  2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-01-01
1  2021-01-02  2021-01-02  2021-01-02
2  2000-01-03  2000-01-03  2000-01-03
```

If you check `.dtypes`:

```
date_1    object
date_2    object
date_3    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, Idk what's wromg, but evry time I am getting the error : AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

And this too after converting object to str, still error

Comment: @PriyaChauhan ok so not all your values are string. I take `df["date_3"]` are datetimes.  Try to run this only on your `date_1` and ``date_2` as shown in your question. In other words,  `df[["date_1", "date_2"]].apply(lambda x:x.str.replace("^00", "20", regex=True))`

Comment: In pandas `str` types are shown as `object`

Comment: @saiden I know that, but also if you have a mixed dates and times in the same series it is shown as object. If a Series is made of all `str`, `.str` works

Comment: Yes sorry, I was referring to her comment. From what I gather if she still has that error perhaps the conversion was not successful.

Comment: Thank you all, I am trying this

Comment: @PriyaChauhan check the follow up